# pandas add lines if not enough samples for a given variable

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose pandas dataframe

```
In [23]: df = pd.DataFrame()
    ...: df['Wafer_Id'] = [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3]
    ...: df['v1'] = np.random.normal(0, 1, 9)
    ...: df['v2'] = np.random.normal(0, 1, 9)


In [23]: 

In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
   Wafer_Id        v1        v2
0         0  0.050987 -1.524646
1         0  0.784595 -0.545002
2         0  1.005748  0.588026
3         1  1.146895  0.196029
4         1  1.570850 -1.609470
5         1 -0.393617  1.091749
6         2  1.366572 -2.189071
7         2  1.444561  0.378211
8         3  1.327378  0.213290
```

for `wafer_id=0` or `1` there are `3` rows while only `2` for `wafer_id = 2` and `3`

I would like to add a line of `0` with `wafer_id=2` and `2` lines of `0` for `wafer_id=3` in order that for each wafer index there are the same number of samples.

How can I do that?

Comment: It depends what you want the corresponding values of ```v1, v2``` to be